# ffmpeg for medium quality

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried using the `-sameq`, and it works and got a good quality for the video, but I noticed the file size had increased greater than the original video.

So how can I adjust for the medium quality? I mean much better than the normal `ffmpeg -i input output` for the mid quality.

Answer (score 5):

More information is needed to answer your question adequately. I don't have enough "reputation" to leave a simple comment for clarification.

1. -sameq is the most misused FFmpeg option. The old documentation used to imply that -sameq meant, "make the output the same quality as the input". [This is not the case](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-November/003212.html).
2. You did not specify which output format you want. Options to control quality can vary depending on your encoder.

When encoding to MPEG-1/2/4 use -qscale instead of -sameq. This option controls your quality level. The scale is linear, with double the qscale being about half the bitrate. 3-5 are good values to try. Use the highest value that looks good to you. A value of 2 can generally be considered visually lossless.

For H.264 use CRF. Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 24 output.mp4
```

Adjust the CRF value to change output quality. 18-28 is a sane range (for 8-bit encoding). Use the highest value that still gives you an acceptable quality. Use the slowest preset you have patience for. Presets are listed in *x264 --help*. A preset is a group of x264 settings that give a speed vs compression tradeoff.